# What is the android method to track HTTP requests

Tags: android, http

I been on interview today and I been asked to provide a method to track an HTTP request, to know when it's ended, and be able to recover from killing the process. My answer was as follow:

Create a Model with 3 states: Start, Finished and Ideal as default. When you start the request, update the model state to Start, when you finished update the model state to Finish, make the model to save its state locally. If you got a crash at the middle, you can recover from the model, assuming that you also keep all the relevant data to the request.

The interviewer told me that there is a more native android way of doing this, he may be spoke about a design pattern, but I don't remember it's name. Do you familiar with anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

A delegate can be used for running the responseReceived callback

Comment: No it's not it. The idea is to keep track over the request.